# Should I file a W-8 BEN for RSUs vesting while I'm in the US?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, employee-stock-options, form-w-8-ben

I just moved from Ireland to the US, mid-July 2022. I will not be considered a "US Person" because I'm not a US citizen and I will be staying less than 182 days in the US. I have some RSU vesting in October 2022, which were granted while I was in Ireland. I understand that I will have to pay only a partial tax for the stocks vesting in October (which should be less than 10%). I have a couple of questions for my situation.

1. I was asked to re-certify my W-8 BEN. Should I still file W-8 BEN with my current US address? Or should it be W-8ECI?
2. Should I ask my broker to withhold only Ireland taxes and not-US taxes? Is it okay to pay the US tax I owe when I file the tax return?

Comment: "I will not be considered a "US Person" because I'm not a US citizen and I will be staying less than 182 days in the US." You may be misreading the rules a bit. You can be a resident alien if you have a green card. Also, the substantial presence test (which you are probably alluding to) doesn't require 182 days or more in the US, but uses a more complex formula.

Comment: @JackFleeting Yes! I don't pass the "substantial presence test".

Comment: @Alex I'm in exactly the same situation as you. Did you ever get a satisfactory answer? As far as I can tell, I need to recertify my W8-BEN and keep part II (claim of tax treaty benefits) blank. When I become a resident alien I will need to start filling a W-4 instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not becoming a US tax resident you should continue using the form W8-BEN. You may also use [form 8233](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-8233) if appropriate. RSU vest is treated as salary income in the US (i.e.: earned income from personal services), and you [should not use W8-ECI](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/iw8eci#en_US_202108_publink1000312376) for salary income.

You'll need to check with your tax advisor if any US taxes are owed and if so how to handle them. I assume the company provides you relocation assistance? If not - you'll need to find a EA/CPA licensed in your State to ask them about it.